# How to dispose a JFrame and recreate it as new without exiting the application?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose, dispatchevent

I have a problem where I have to use two `JFrame`s, so we can forget about good/bad practice.

Now that when we are past this point.

My Two `JFrame`s are

1. `LoginFrame`
2. `MainFrame`

I want to sign out of `MainFrame` to `LoginFrame` and vice versa. In doing so, I want both the frames to open fresh.
Just like how we instantiate them, i.e.

### MainFrame.class

```
//on signout button event
new LoginFrame().setVisible(true);
dispose(); //it will dispose this frame and destroy its UI components and free resources etc etc.
```

Similarly,

### LoginFrame.class

```
//on signin button event
new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
dispose(); //it will dispose this frame and destroy its UI components and free resources etc etc.
```

Now, this is working well but the problem is that I have a `keyDispatchEvent` in `MainFrame` which is executing a number of times I login after signout (without closing the application).

I believe that even after disposing, the `JFrame` it isn't actually disposed. So when I type any shortkey, previously disposed frame objects and new object of `MainFrame` are all dispatching their event. How can I lose ( I mean really dispose) all previous objects so that this event is only fired for current object?

### MainFrame.class

```
final static KeyboardFocusManager keyManager=KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();

keyManager.addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() 
{

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) 
        {
           // if key is alt+r  
           {
               signout(); // getting called repeatedly on single key release 
           }
        }
});
```

What I don't want is using same objects because they will have previous state/information/changes. Just want to get rid of disposed objects.

Also, I have to work with `KeyboardManager` to `DispatchKeyEvent` in this case.

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: Pleaaaaaaseeee?

Comment: *I have an keyDispatchEvent i* - Typically you use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to listen for a specific key stroke and then perform a specific Action. All Swing components use Key Bindings in this way. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You should also look into using a `CardLayout` and possibly `JDialog`s too as opposed to using multiple `JFrame`s as this is seen as bad practice

Comment: You only have to create the login JFrame (should be a JDialog) one time.  You can clear the text from the fields and use the JFrame over and over again.  The same holds true for your main JFrame.  Create it one time, and clear the fields so you can use it over and over again.

Comment: Guys, thank you for your response. As I have clearly stated in my question, DavidKroukamp that I have to use separate frame and @camickr KeyDispatchEvent in MainFrame instead of KeyBindings. My real question was about why is this event still attached to exposed objects? And how can I make them gone(disposed) forever(keyDispatchEvent won't occur on disposed objects.) and Gilbert Le Blanc use fresh objects only.

Comment: *if key is alt+r* - no you don't have to use KeyDispatchEvent, you are choosing to use KeyDispatchEvent and you are having problems. Key bindings is the way all Swing components handle mapping an Action to a KeyStroke which is what you appear to be doing (based on the few random lines of code posted). You still haven't posted an [mre] demonstrating the problem, so all we can do is suggest proper Swing design solutions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the below code does what you want. Since you didn't post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I can only guess what you want from your [poor] problem description and your insistence on [[your] way or the highway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_way_or_the_highway).

> the problem is that I have a `keyDispatchEvent` in `MainFrame` which is executing a number of times I login after signout

My guess is that you keep adding the same `KeyEventDispatcher` to the `KeyboardFocusManager` and each one that gets added will execute. So if you add the same `KeyEventDispatcher` three times, it will execute three times. I assume you only want to add it once and therefore you need to remove it when it is no longer required.

I also assume that when you launch your application, you want the `LoginFrame` to be displayed first. Hence I added a `main` method to class `LoginFrame`, below.

Class `LoginFrame`

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LoginFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public LoginFrame() {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().removeKeyEventDispatcher(MainFrame.ked);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton signin = new JButton("sign in");
        signin.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(signin);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new LoginFrame().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Class `MainFrame`

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    final static KeyboardFocusManager keyManager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();

    private static boolean  done;
    static KeyEventDispatcher ked;

    public MainFrame() {
        keyManager.removeKeyEventDispatcher(ked);
        ked = new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
                int key = ke.getKeyCode();
                int modifiers = ke.getModifiersEx();
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_R  &&  (modifiers & KeyEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK) == KeyEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK) {
                    if (done) {
                        done = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        done = true;
                        actionPerformed(null);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        keyManager.addKeyEventDispatcher(ked);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton signout = new JButton("sign out");
        signout.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(signout);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        new LoginFrame().setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
}
```

NOTES:

- I don't know why, but each time I hit Alt+R on the keyboard, the event dispatcher fires twice. Hence the `done` flag.